# Regex findall then split values into columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Using `str.extract` then a str split, the error I am getting is:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 18, placement implies 1

The raw data split looks like this:

```
[('', '', '', '', '220', '5', '1', '97.35', '94.69', '641632.16', '2998.28', '80', '', '226', '6', '220', '0', '443')]

[('08/02/2019', '', '79', '123', '162', '5', '1', '71.68', '69.03', '441381.64', '2829.37', '14', '', '226', '2', '224', '62', '271')]

[('08/03/2019', '175', '58', '71', '162', '5', '1', '71.68', '69.03', '441381.64', '2829.37', '14', '', '226', '2', '224', '62', '271')]

[('08/04/2019', '162', '88', '85', '165', '0', '0', '73.01', '73.01', '467773.78', '2834.99', '10', '', '226', '1', '225', '60', '272')]
```

Script :

```
df['Description'].str.findall(expression)
df
expression = r"([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})?\s{5,6}(\d+)?\s{3}(\d+)?\s{3,4}(\d+)?\s{2,10}(\d+)?[|]\s{4}(\d+)?\s{5}(\d+)?[|]\s{1}(\d+[.]\d+)\s{1}(\d+[.]\d+)[|]\s{2}(\d+[.]\d+)\s{4}(\d+[.]\d+)[|]\s{3,4}(\d+)?\s{3,5}(\d+)?[|]\s{2}(\d+)?\s{3,4}(\d+)?\s{2,3}(\d+)?\s{2,4}(\d+)?[|]\s{3,4}(\d+)?"
```

`df['Description']` is the raw data before splitting.

Comment: cannot understand from this what you are trying to do. What are `expression` and `df`?

Comment: Hi @NFB, Thanks for bringing that up. expression is the regex, while df is the data frame from a csv.

Comment: Looks like a usual problem with `str.findall`. Replace all capturing groups with non-capturing ones (or, `(\d+)?` => `\d*`). However, the pattern is too clumsy - what is it supposed to match?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, ran the following code and that's how i got the error for values.   ``` # gg['Desc'] = gg['Description'].str.extract(expression)
        # gg['Desc'] = gg['Desc'].split(', ')
        # print (gg['Desc'])```

Comment: No,  I meant to replace capturing groups with non-capturing ones. Not using `str.extract`.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, Not sure what you meant. But just re-ran the script using  valueA = gg['Description'].str.extract(expression, expand=True)  instead and now it works.

Comment: `.findall(r'(?:[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})?\s{5,6}\d*\s{3}\d*\s{3,4}\d*\s{2,10}\d*[|]\s{4}\d*\s{5}\d*\|\s(?:\d+\.\d+)\s(?:\d+\.\d+)\|\s{2}(?:\d+\.\d+)\s{4}(?:\d+\.\d+)\|\s{3,4}\d*\s{3,5}\d*\|\s{2}\d*\s{3,4}\d*\s{2,3}\d*\s{2,4}\d*\|\s{3,4}\d*')`. If  `str.extract` works, no idea what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked

`valueA = gg['Description'].str.extract(expression, expand=True)`

but the code, did not:

`gg['Des'] = gg['Description'].str.extract(expression, expand=True)`

`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 18, placement implies 1`